# How To Blend Images In OpenGL ES 2

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, shader, opengl-es-2.0

I am making an android application in which I want to load three images into the OpenGL surface and Blend them. The blending is not one of the default functions, I want to take the average and median of the three images.

AVERAGE:

```
 pixel.r  = (PixelOne.r + PixelTwo.r + PixelThree.r)/3
 pixel.g  = (PixelOne.g + PixelTwo.g + PixelThree.g)/3
 pixel.b  = (PixelOne.b + PixelTwo.b + PixelThree.b)/3
```

MEDIAN:

```
 pixel = somemedianfunction(PixelOne,PixelTwo,PixelThree);
```

I am able to draw images one above another(-z-direction, into the screen). I want to know how to perform the above calculations?

Answer (score 0):

To find the median of 3 numbers I would do:

```
PixelMin.r = min(PixelOne.r, min(PixelTwo.r, PixelThree.r))
PixelMax.r = max(PixelOne.r, max(PixelTwo.r, PixelThree.r))
PixelMedian.r = PixelOne.r + PixelTwo.r + PixelThree.r - PixelMin.r - PixelMax.r
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I want to know, where Can I do this calculations?